# Phaser Js- How to resize an image and divide resized image into pieces?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to resize an image, then i want to divide that scaled image into multiple pieces. how to do this in phaser js?

Comment: "use BitmapData objects and copy parts of the full image to these as needed using the copyPixels function." I have found the answer from slack.

Answer (score 0):

get your hands on it I have found the example code [bitmapdata-copy pixel](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/bitmapdata/copy-pixels)